# How to display row of images in a repeater control vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to make a image slider with a repeater control in asp.net. I have a div with a repeater control in it with images, but I can't figure out how to make it display vertically instead of horizontally. Can anyone point me to the correct CSS style? I've tried using vertical-align property on the div. Here is a link to the javascript file [carosuelLite](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ganeshmax/jcarousellite/master/jquery.jcarousellite.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jcarousellite.js"> 
</script>
<div class="container">
     <div id="navicontainer">
         <ul>
             <asp:Repeater ID="RptSlider" runat="server">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <li><a href="#">
                         <asp:Image ID="imgSlide1" runat="server"   
                           ImageUrl='<%#Container.DataItem %>' Height="128" 
                           Width="128"/>
                     </li>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

here is the css code

```
#navicontainer{
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#navcontainer").jCarouselLite({
            hoverPause: true,
            visible: 3,
            auto: 500,
            speed: 2500
            vertical:true;
         });
      });
</script>
```

Update: I was reading through the jcarouselLite documentation and it mention if i use the vertical: true property it would vertically align the slider. Yet When i tried it. Still nothing happen. I have this placed in a wrapper, maybe it's limiting the size able to display by my content place holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `asp:DataList` control instead of `Repeater` to align it vertically or horizontally, as your choice. It provides a `RepeatDirection` attribute to do the same.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx2f3ks(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I will use that.